# Restrict Devise password recovery to only certain users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

My app has a pre-subscription system to allow users to subscribe without password.

But malicious users who haven't finished their subscription (= don't have a password yet) could follow the password recovery process to set theirselves a password and brake the usual subscription process.

So I would like Devise to provide password recovery to only the users who are validated (namely users who finished their subscription).

If a non-validated user is entering his email to try to get a new password, I would like to show him the "email not found" error, as if he wasn't found at all.

I didn't find where to override Devise to add such a scope.

[This method](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/recoverable.rb#L114) from the `Recoverable` seems to fit but I haven't been able to customize it:

```
# Attempt to find a user by its email. If a record is found, send new
# password instructions to it. If user is not found, returns a new user
# with an email not found error.
# Attributes must contain the user's email
def send_reset_password_instructions(attributes={})
  recoverable = find_or_initialize_with_errors(reset_password_keys, attributes, :not_found)
  recoverable.send_reset_password_instructions if recoverable.persisted?
  recoverable
end
```

So for the moment I overrode the `PasswordsController` but this is not a clean solution.

```
class Users::PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController

  def create
    if resource_params[:email].present? && resource_class.registration_complete.where(email: resource_params[:email]).none?
      self.resource = resource_class.new
      self.resource.errors.add(:email, :not_found)
      render :new
    else
      super
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: To others who are looking for a solution to this question, this answer may be effective: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28947108/3650105.