# Multiple Devise controller overrides

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to restrict Devise password resets for particular users. I found this thread which describes overriding PasswordsController:

[Restrict Devise password recovery to only certain users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25856582/restrict-devise-password-recovery-to-only-certain-users)

My problem is, I'm already overriding registrations with my own registrations controller:

devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }

My registrations controller inherits from Devise::RegistrationsController, and according to the above thread my Password controller will need to inherit Devise::PasswordsController, and thus be a separate controller. How can I have multiple Devise controllers to facilitate these overrides?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
:controllers => {registrations: 'registrations' }
```

uses your custom registrations controller, so adding `{passwords: 'passwords'}` will use your custom passwords

The complete line should be

```
controller.devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations', passwords: 'passwords'  }
```

Comment: :controllers => {registrations: 'registrations' } uses your custom registrations controller, so adding {passwords: 'passwords'} will use your custom passwords controller.